# How to select last cell in a column and insert it into another sheet in last open cell

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Just started coding with excel in VB. The problem I am having is this:

I want to copy the last cell in a column on one sheet, then paste it into the next open cell in a column on the next sheet. If it is at all possible can I have it do this automatically instead of having to call the function or click a button every time?

Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub UpdatePromoCalendar()
Dim LR As Long
Dim TR As Long
LR = WorksheetFunction.Max(20, Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
TR = WorksheetFunction.Max(20, Range("O" & Rows.Count).End(x1Up).Row - 1)
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("O" & TR).CopySpecial xlCopyValues
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & LR).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

Now it works using the paste option above with the LR. But I can't get it to copy the last populated cell in the column.

Sorry if it's a simple fix I am new to using excel macros and VB in excel.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: When you run `Rows.Count`, what sheet do you expect that to be on? You need to add the sheet name, otherwise, it'll just use whatever the active sheet is.  So, I'm think your `TR` should be `Sheets("Sheet2").Rows.Count`

Comment: With what @BruceWayne stated you need to add the parent sheet to both ranges in the Max function.  Otherwise it does not know on which sheet column A and Column O it should be looking for the last cell.  `Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Sheets("Sheet2").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added the code that you suggested to add and so far im getting the same error. I keep getting an error saying application defined-error or object-defined error. It then highlights: TR = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("O" & Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count).End(x1Up).Row

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a macro I decided to redo my spreadsheet and go with a pivot table with slicers. I created separate sheets with each item and added a new column called price master. This way I could then filter the results with the slicers showing a cleaner and easier to use template.

The macro was a lot of trouble and basically was taking the place of the slicer which was a waste of time doing in the long run.